# MS Azure Pay As you go plan Developer hosting charges

Tags: mongodb, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

Can anybody Help me resolving the Query Regarding the MS Azure Hosting.
I'm developer and I would like to host my ASP.NET Web API's.

One month of Free Trial i have used it.

It was really great and awesome.
I would like to know if any one using pay as you go plan
How much it will be charged to.DB usage will be less.

MY focus as mentioned below

> 1. Application
>      ASP.NET WEBAPI's
>      NODE.JS Appplications

Mobile Applications

> > DataBase
> >        MONGODB
> >        SQL SERVER

Thanks Ton in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the Azure Web site where you'll find detailed pricing:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/overview/

I suggest you use the pricing calculator found here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/